# Elasticsearch take snapshot then clean indices which older than 7 days

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch 7.4.1 cluster for storing logs, and i have this SLM pattern applied in my cluster

```
curl -X PUT "afghanistan-01.elastic:9200/_slm/policy/nightly-snapshots?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "schedule": "0 30 1 * * ?", 
  "name": "<nightly-snap-{now/d}>", 
  "repository": "backup_repository",
  "config": { 
    "indices": ["*"] 
  }
}
```

so this SLM takes snapshot daily at 01:30 AM.
And i want to delete indices which is older than 7 days after the successful snapshot completion
so is there any way to do that using the policies?
i know how to do it using Bash, but i think it's better to use internal mechanism to do this

Comment: You can use Curator to do that for you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/about-features.html

Comment: What you need is [Index Lifecycle Management (ILM)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html)